Merge tags for DSA and ECDSA?
Currently we have both of these tags:

dsa (40 questions)
ecdsa (85 questions)

Both are basically the same algorithm, just implemented over different groups. Would it make sense to merge ECDSA into DSA and use elliptic-curves and finite-field if the question is group specific?

Mission complete.

Merging ecdsa with dsa – and accordingly making ECDSA a synonym of DSA – makes sense to me. Especially, when looking at your argumentation related to the availability for group-specific tagging when needed.
Based on that, maybe we should handle ECDH in an alike manner… meaning: ecdh could be merged with diffie-hellman. The elliptic-curves tag could then be used to differ ECDH from other DH, and ECDH could be made a synonym of DH.
